# R data.table randomly pops out historical warnings

Tags: r, data.table, warnings

It's a really weird problem, and will try my best to describe it.

One month ago, I ran the following code:

```
dataDT[,colA := ...][, colB := NULL][, colC := NULL]    # which pops out an error
In `[.data.table`(dataDT[, `:=`(colC, NULL)],  ... :
  Adding new column 'colC' then assigning NULL (deleting it).
```

Since then, whenever 'dataDT' is used to store values, the same error randomly pops out.

1. The frequency has been increasing.
2. Once it occurs in a R session, same warnings keep appearing until the session is closed.
3. I've tried to reinstall R, R studio, keeping them updated; re-downloaded all packages.
4. The following code won't stop warnings from re-appearing: 
   assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())

Here is an example:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.4                         
year           2018                        
month          03                          
day            15                          
svn rev        74408                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
nickname       Someone to Lean On          
There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Any method to solve it once for all?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plyr_1.8.4           haven_1.1.1          RDCOMClient_0.93-0.2 XLConnect_0.2-14     XLConnectJars_0.2-14
 [6] ggplot2_2.2.1        crayon_1.3.4         installr_0.19.0      taRifx_1.0.6         doParallel_1.0.11   
[11] iterators_1.0.9      foreach_1.4.4        stringdist_0.9.4.7   NMOF_1.2-2           stringr_1.3.0       
[16] zoo_1.8-1            lubridate_1.7.2      RODBC_1.3-15         svMisc_1.0-2         readxl_1.0.0        
[21] data.table_1.10.4-3  rstudioapi_0.7      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16     cellranger_1.1.0 compiler_3.4.4   pillar_1.2.1     forcats_0.3.0    tools_3.4.4     
 [7] tibble_1.4.2     gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  rlang_0.2.0      yaml_2.1.18      rJava_0.9-9     
[13] grid_3.4.4       reshape2_1.4.3   magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0     codetools_0.2-15 colorspace_1.3-2
[19] stringi_1.1.7    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: What is your version of `data.table`? This issue came up a long time ago but hadn't been raised in some time so we assumed. it was fixed (we never identified a root cause). see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1781) and [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1690)

Comment: @MichaelChirico data.table 1.10.4-3. Just saw your post, seems there is no solution because unreproducible?

Comment: If you're able to create a reproducible example, please do file a new issue and reference this post. the problem was quite annoying when I was encountering it (thankfully not for several years). You might also try updating to the latest development version, there's been some work on memory leaks lately. maybe it was finally caught.